# VSTO Outlook 2007 Add-in Context Menu CommandBarButton click event

Tags: vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin

I need to add a button to the context menu of the inbox.  I have this working fine.  What I need to figure out is in the implementation of the event handler how do I determine which item/items was clicked?

```
private void AddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay += Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay;
}

private void Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar commandBar, Selection selection)
{
   commandBar.Controls[1].BeginGroup = true; // add seperator before first menu

   var cmdButtonCopy = (CommandBarButton)commandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 1, Missing.Value, 1, Missing.Value);
   cmdButtonCopy.Caption = "&Copy Message";
   cmdButtonCopy.Click += cmdButtonCopy_Click;
}

private void cmdButtonCopy_Click(CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool canceldefault)
{
     // no sender/event args to determine which item was clicked ...
}
```

In the cmdButtonCopy_Click event handler I need to copy the specific item that was right-clicked but I can't figure out how to tell which item was clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tag property inside the CommandBarButton

Comment: This isn't the "best" possible way I was hoping for, but it works.  I'm setting the Tag property to the EntryId of the mail item then in the click handler I'm getting that item back from the Application.Session.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adam I'm trying to do the exact same thing.  Could you please elaborate on how you did this?  How/where did you get the EntryId of the selected mail item?  How did you access the mail item at all in the click handler?  Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have written the code to solve your issue have a look at it:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemContextMenuDisplay += new ApplicationEvents_11_ItemContextMenuDisplayEventHandler(Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay);
    }

    void Application_ItemContextMenuDisplay(CommandBar CommandBar, Selection Selection)
    {
        CommandBarButton mycmdbarbtn = (CommandBarButton)CommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,missing, missing, 1,true);
        mycmdbarbtn.Caption = "Test Button";           
        mycmdbarbtn.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(mycmdbarbtn_Click);           
        mailitm=Selection.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1]; // to get the currently selected mailitem.
    }

    void mycmdbarbtn_Click(CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The subject of the clicked mail is " + mailitm.Subject);
    }
```

Comment: The only thing you're missing here is the global variable for `mailitm` that you're setting.